# Reference request: Practical string algorithms

Tags: algorithms, strings

I think I have quite a good understanding of string algorithms. However, a couple of days ago, I came across this post: [Find all pairs of strings in a set with Levenshtein distance < d](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53299/find-all-pairs-of-strings-in-a-set-with-levenshtein-distance-d)

I was wondering, whether there are more string algorithms which do not have good worst-case guarantees but are good in practice. I guess these are not taught at some university string algorithms courses, as the professors want to teach algorithms with good theoretical running times

Comment: (1) For a start, there's a 20-year-old [Dan Gusfield's](https://www.google.com/search?q=dan+gusfield+strings) book. (2) Isn't "string algorithms" too broad?

Comment: I know this book but I have not found in it any heuristics, like the one mentioned above. Could you please more specific? I don't think "string algorithms" is too broad and I don't think just "algorithms" would be too broad.