# Find approximate 'best' matching pairs by calculating the fewest possible weights

Tags: weighted-graphs, bipartite-matching, assignment-problem

My specific problem is as follows:

- Given two list of texts (in the order of 5 to 50 items)
- Find best matching pairs with their corresponding matching score (weight)
- Where each item can only be matched once with another item (from the other list)
- While minimizing the calculation of the weights ([Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) in my case)
- Every score can be between 0.0 (no match) and 1.0 (perfect match)
- I may only require pairs to be matched, that meet a certain threshold

Because the edit distance is quite expensive to calculate, it is the bottleneck.
At the same time, I may be able to exclude some edges by calculating the upper limit (if they don't meet the threshold).

I guess this could be a special case of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Assuming the size of list 1 is `n` and the size of list 2 is `m`.

It seems in order to apply most common algorithm, one need to calculate all of the scores between all possible pairs.
i.e. in this case it would be `n * m`

One approach I tried to far is:

- Copy `list 2` to `remaining list 2`
- For each `item 1` in `list 1`

  - Find best match meeting threshold of `item 1` in `list 1`:

    - Copy `remaining list 2` to `temp list 2`
    - Sort `temp list 2` by `approximate score` between `item 1` and each item in `temp list 2` (in descending order)
    - Remove items from `temp list 2` where approximate score is below threshold
    - For each `item 2` in `temp list 2`:

      - Calculate a `expensive score` between `item 1` and `item 2`
      - If `expensive score` is `1.0`: Return pair between `item 1` and `item 2`
      - If `expensive score` is meeting threshold: Save `item 2` as `best matching item 2`
    - Return pair between `item 1` and `best matching item 2`
  - Remove `item 2` of matched pair from `remaining list 2`

I am thinking this can probably be improved by initially using the first found matching pair meeting the threshold.
And then later see if unmatched `item 1` can be matched with an already paired `item 2`, whereas `item 2` could also be matched with another `item 1`.

Do any existing algorithms address a similar problem?

### Additional Note: Edit Distance Approximations

Currently I am using the following two approximations (both used by Python's `difflib`):

- Based on the length, we can calculate the maximum score we could get (e.g. if `item 1` is only half the length of `item 2` then the score can't be more than `0.5`)
- Intersection of character counts

Comment: Unless there's some other properties of your distance function, you have no choice but to evaluate all $nm$ distances. So please describe your 'edit distance' function in more detail.

Comment: Thank you @orlp for the feedback. It is the Levenshtein distance. I edited the question to add the link to it. I was hoping there would be a some sort of BFS algorithm that could stop when it seems "good enough". Which I guess would be if every item has been paired up (within threshold) or wouldn't have a suitable pair otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps the ideas in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/53299/find-all-pairs-of-strings-in-a-set-with-levenshtein-distance-d) will be useful. More generally, there could be a way to calculate all pairwise distance faster than calculating them individually, especially if you're less interested in pairs where the distances are large.